# Online Slot Management and recruitement tool for lab studies

Tags: lab-management

In Human-Computer Interaction and Psychology (and others) lab studies are performed quite often. Although searching quite a bit, I did not find a tool/piece of software or application to provide a link for students to sign up for the study on a specific date and manage time slots. Besides our homebrewn approach I could not find anything on the net. Is there anybody out there with a better service than google calendar ?

Comment: The one time I had to do this, we coded one (this was before Google was even close to being a household name). There seem to be several free iPhone apps handling your needs (key word: appointment scheduler); maybe have a look if one does what you want well.